# Standalone attribute selector in CSS

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am using standalone attribute selectors since I discovered [AMCSS](https://amcss.github.io/). Recently I switched to [cssnext](http://cssnext.io/) from [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and discovered that syntax highlighting seems to be broken in [Atom](http://atom.io) and some other places/apps that I tested.

```css
/* So this thing will be highlighted properly */

h1[foo] { font-weight: bold; }

/* and this thing not */

[foo] { font-weight: bold; }
```

The weird thing is that I couldn't find any examples of standalone attribute selector in specifications, but they work perfectly. All the examples uses combined selectors like `h1[foo]`.

**TL;DR**

Is `[foo]` the same as `*[foo]` and is safe to use, or is it just a coincidence that it works?

Comment: Yes according to [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) attribute selectors should be like `element[attribute]` or `*[attribute]`. `[attribute]` works (I would expect it to), but I would say it is safer to stick to the official syntax unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Yes `*[attribute]` and `[attribute]` are same, for now at least.

Comment: I wonder if the relation of `*[attribute]` and `[attribute]` is anyhow different than `*.class` and `.class`. Do you think there is some easy way to check browser's implementation of CSS selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `h1[foo]` versus `[foo]` is the same as `h1.bar` vs `.bar`.

Comment: I've found that CSS3 treats `div.value` and `div[class~=value]` as having the same meaning in https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#class-html and below there is also an example of `*.pastoral` and `.pastoral` being the same. 

So I guess what follows is that `*[foo]` and `[foo]` **should** be treated the same by browsers. The question is then if browsers implemented it with the same conclusions :-P